# How to get a string between 2 known words

Tags: vb6

My problem is to get a string as described above ! In my case

```
1234;0020001212;6565656AEBCD698798832
```

The string,I want is "0020001212" , My known words are ";". 
I tried Mid() but my value is not stable , variable !
so, please help me to find this answer. Thank y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode it:

```
theLine = "1234;0020001212;6565656AEBCD698798832"

Dim arr() As String
arr = Split(theLine, ";")

Debug.Print arr(0)
Debug.Print arr(1)
Debug.Print arr(2)
```

For

```
1234
0020001212
6565656AEBCD698798832
```

Comment: I got runtime error 52, bad file name or number ! help me !Please

Comment: My bad, don't use `Line` as a variable name, rename it.

Comment: I got it, Special thanks to you. As I described as above I am absolute beginner, thank you for your patience :D

Answer (score 1):

Use the Split function and use ";" as the delimiter to convert the string into an array of strings.

```
Dim arr() As String
arr = Split("a;b;c", ";")
```

Then you can access the second element of the array to get your value.

Comment: Wow, look at the faster people.

Answer (score 0):

Use split function, using ";" as separator